# Getting started with Android code samples - permissions error

Tags: android

New to android. Running Eclipse on Ubuntu 9.10 with Android SDK plugin installed and working. Trying to get some code samples from http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/get.html , and following its procedure to load said samples in Eclipse yields:

```
Parent of resource: /home/user/android-sdk/platforms/android-4/samples/Notepad/.project is marked as read-only.
```

chmod is not recursive, so I entered ~/android-sdk/platforms and "chmod 777 *" ie. all folders in /platforms. Still doesnt work. Appears to be be a bug in Eclipse that wants to create the project in the SDK folder rather than under ~/workspace.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but still an issue with the newest release of ADT.

To get around the issue and avoiding having to chmod the entire sdk platform, you can just change ownership of the project itself to your profile instead of the default root profile it is set to.

if you issue:

```
sudo chmod -R yourProfileName YourProjectDir/
```

Where yourProfileName is your user profile name,  it should resolve the issue. If you are unsure what your profile name is, it is usually the name of your home directory in OSX.  In windows, you should be able to find it somewhere under control panel -> profiles.

Answer (score 0):

The far better solution is to select a choice such as "copy into workspace" when creating/importing the Eclipse project.

This has the benefit of leaving the original source files in a clean state, where you can easily refer back to them if your modifications to an example break it.

Answer (score -1):

Whoops. Chmod does have a recursive functionality (of course):

```
chmod 777 android-sdk -R
```

but that seems to have borked the Eclipse workspace.

Comment: Note: I assume you're on a Unix system of some sort. Setting file permissions to executable willy-nilly is sloppy and in some cases a potential security hole. What you *should* be doing is "chmod -R u+rw android-sdk". This symbolic form gives the user read and write access to all files and directories, and leaves the executable flag alone. There is no reason to give extra permissions to "group" and "other".